# How to split string but ignore until found certain char?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I'm tasked to create an intrepreter for c#

basically I want to split this string:

`"multiply (add 5 5) 5"`

into an array of string:

`["multiply", "(add 5 5)", "5"]`

if I'm using string.Split based on delimiter of space: " ", the result will be:

`["multiply", "(add", "5", "5)", "5"]`
which is not what I'm expecting

Is this achievable in C#?

Edit:
I also need to support nested expression:

`"multiply (add (add 2 5) 5) 5"`

For example above, needs to become:

`["multiply", "(add (add 2 5) 5)", 5]`

Comment: You might look into `Regex.Split`, which means learning something about regular expressions.

Comment: Look at [Recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). Its implementation in C# is described in detail [here](https://flylib.com/books/en/3.12.1.261/1/).

Comment: You need something more sophisticated that simple string manipulation to parse a grammar. If you don't want to write your own try antlr or irony.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the very basic use cases you have provided, you could achieve the 'interpretation' by looping through your source string, keeping track of which nested level you are currently in (if any), and using a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-7.0) to build your interpreted parts character by character.

You could implement a method containing the following logic:

1. Create an empty `StringBuilder` object, which will hold the part of the source string you are currently interpreting
2. Create a counter to keep track of which nested level you are currently on (starting at 0 -- no nested level)
3. Loop through your source string, character by character. For each character:

   1. Check whether the character is a space, and whether you are currently inside a nested part or not.

      - If the character *is* a space and you are *not* currently inside a nested part, it means you have reaced the end of the part that is currently being interpreted. Create a string of your `StringBuilder` object, return it and clear the `StringBuilder` object to prepare for the next part to be interpreted. Continue to the next character in the source string (i.e. skip the subsequent steps for the current character).
   2. Check whether the current character is an opening inner delimiter ( `'('` ). If it is, it means that you are entering the next nested level. Update your *nested level counter* to reflect that.
   3. If the current character was *not* an opening inner delimiter; check whether it is a *closing* inner delimiter ( `')'` ). If it is, update your *nested level counter* to reflect that.
   4. Append the current character to your `StringBuilder` object.
4. *After* having looped through the whole source string, make sure to return the current content of your `StringBuilder` object as a string. (Unless your source string ends with a space character, the `StringBuilder` object will at this point contain the final interpreted part.)

Here is a possible implementation:

```csharp
private static IEnumerable<string> GetInterpretation(string source)
{
    var delimiter = ' ';
    var innerDelimiter = (Opening: '(', Closing: ')');
    
    StringBuilder currentPart = new StringBuilder();
    
    var innerLevel = 0;
    
    Func<bool> isInnerPart = () => innerLevel > 0;
    
    foreach (var ch in source)
    {
        if (ch == delimiter && !isInnerPart())
        {
            yield return currentPart.ToString();
            
            currentPart.Clear();
            
            continue;
        }
        
        if (ch == innerDelimiter.Opening)
        {
            innerLevel++;
        }
        else if (ch == innerDelimiter.Closing)
        {
            innerLevel--;
        }
        
        currentPart.Append(ch);
    }
    
    if (currentPart.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return currentPart.ToString();
    }
}
```

If your input string variable is named `source`, you can use the method as follows:

```csharp
var interpretation = GetInterpretation(source).ToArray();
```

For the given inputs, the resulting output is:

```csharp
var source = "multiply (add 5 5) 5";
```

> multiply
> (add 5 5)
> 5

```csharp
var source = "multiply (add (add 2 5) 5) 5";
```

> multiply
> (add (add 2 5) 5)
> 5

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iF60Sa).

---

**Note:** As stated, this logic and implementation is naive and can be used for the described *simple use case*.

It assumes:

- you also want to split up words that are separated by *only* a space
  (as opposed to a space *in combination with* a parenthesis)
  --> `"ABC DEF (GHI) JKL MNO"` will be interpreted as `"ABC", "DEF", "(GHI)", "JKL", "MNO"`
- nested parts (wrapped inside `( )`) that are on the top 'nesting level' are *always* preceded and succeeded by a space
  --> `"ABC DEF(GHI)JKL MNO"` will hence be interpreted as `"ABC", "DEF(GHI)JKL", "MNO"`

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the string by  `(` , `)` . In order not to lose the character itself, replace it with two characters:

```
 string s = "multiply (add 5 5) 5";
 string[] reslts = s.Replace("(","((").Replace(")", "))")
                  .Split(new string[] { " (", ") " },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

result:

> ["multiply", "(add 5 5)", "5"]

### Edit:

```
string s = "multiply (add (add 2 5) 5) 5";
var start=s.Select((b, i) => b.Equals('(') ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).FirstOrDefault();
var end = s.Select((b, i) => b.Equals(')') ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).LastOrDefault();

s = s.Insert(start, "#").Insert(end+2, "#");
string[] reslts = s.Split('#');
```

result:

> ["multiply", "(add (add 2 5) 5)", 5]

---